# Sorting an NSArray keeping original indexes rather than values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, nsarray

I have an array of values, and I'd like to sort it from highest to lowest values. Here's my array:

```
@[@0.985517248005697843460382, @0.000103821940243745174581, @0.002930049254083499140483, @0.006089428685598983863325, @0.000169959081717878927225   @0.038708805305937427077012, @0.005785644142951103588435, @0.003949420720490224266663   @0.003306789895982742942537, @0.005520713777168946394258];
```

What's the most efficient way to create a new array, but instead of containing the sorted values, it would contain the indexes from the original array?

Currently this is what I'm doing:

```
NSArray *array = @[@3, @5, @7, @2, @4, @4.1, @1, @10];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *arraySortedByOriginalIndexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.count; i++) {
    NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject:sortedArray[i]];
    [arraySortedByOriginalIndexes addObject:@(index)];
}
```

Comment: They're `NSNumbers` of type `double`. I'll post an example in 2 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple solution if no numbers in array are equal.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];

NSMutableArray *mutableIndexes = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSNumber *number in sortedArray) {
    [mutableIndexes addObject:@([array indexOfObject:number])];
}
NSArray *indexes = [mutableIndexes copy];
```

Again, it only works when no numbers are equal.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey! Can Fast Enumeration be trusted in terms of guaranteeing an order? In the case that 2 numbers are equal, does it return the first one it finds?

Comment: What is the point of the `[mutableIndexes copy]` ?  Did you really want `[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableIndexes]`?

Comment: @KingPolygon It can for an array

Comment: @KingPolygon fast enumeration always walks an array in order.

Comment: @Paulw11 I keep things immutable until they cannot be immutable. So yes, I do `-copy` a lot.

Comment: But a copy of an NSMutableArray is an NSMutableArray no matter what type you assign it to. That is why I suggested you really want arrayWithArray

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm sorry, but `-copy` returns an `NSArray`. `-mutableCopy` returns an `NSMutableArray`. It's specified in [`NSArray`s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray).

Comment: Huh. So it does. How non intuitive.  My apologies

Comment: @Paulw11 Ask me about the time I declared `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *items`. The crashes were very confusing.